# Post not meeting our standards

Tags: support

Whenever I write a shorter post and direct one or two  line question , it always comes that the "post does not meet our quality standards". So how can the site judge that the simple direct question is not of quality ? It often leads to addition of information not really needed.

Answer (score 3):

The details of the algorithm used are kept secret by the Stack Exchange team, but the community is aware of a few pointers that can mean you see this error less:

- Use proper capitalisation and punctuation in both question body and title
- Use formatting styles correctly
- Make your posts a decent length

It seems from your post that it's the length requirement that's tripping you up.  Remember that even direct questions should include what you have found out yourself from research and enough context to make them answerable.  You should never need to just repeat the title in the post body.

For more information (with the caveat that the tips are largely about programming related content), see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92075/176080) on the central meta.